# Limit product quantity to 1 per customer in magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to limit the quantity of a product purchased by a customer to 1 per day. We are going to have something like deal and day and targeting consumers. We do not want some one to buy high quantities. Could some one guide me as to what the general approach should be to do this? Thanks.

I noticed that there is a table `sales_flat_order_item` which contains `products_id` for an order, a join of this table with `sales_flat_order` should give me product_id for the orders placed by the customer. How do i access this table data directly and perform the join operation the magento way? Do i need to create a new module? or modify a existing module?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a coupon/coupons for this. Leave the product at the original price and hand out a coupon to the targeted customers. Make sure that you set it to "only applies to 1 item" and can only be used once.

Regards,
Kenny